# Polymorphic assignment with subroutine possibly causing data corruption in Fortran

Tags: oop, fortran, polymorphism, overloading

The following test program attempts to perform something similar to Fortran's `pack` intrinsics with a polymorphic derived type. In this example, the odd elements (1,3,5,7,9) of the 10-sized array are packed to positions (1:5). All assignments work besides the 1st element:

```
module assign
        implicit none
        private


        type, public :: t
             integer :: a              
             contains
                   procedure :: destroy=>t_destroy
                   procedure :: assign=>t_assign
                   generic :: assignment(=) =>assign 
        end type t

   contains


   elemental subroutine t_destroy(this)
        class(t), intent(inout) :: this
        this%a = 0
   end subroutine t_destroy

   subroutine t_assign(this,that)
        class(t), intent(inout) :: this
        class(t), intent(in) :: that

        call this%destroy() ! Clean memory first

        select type (thatPtr=>that)
           type is (t)
               this%a = thatPtr%a    
        end select

   end subroutine t_assign
end module assign

program test
        use assign
        type(t), allocatable :: t1(:)

        allocate(t1(10))
        
        do i=1,10
          t1(i)%a = i
        end do  
        
        n = 0
        do i=1,10
          if (mod(i,2)/=0) then 
              n = n + 1
              t1(n) = t1(i)
              print *, 'i=',i,' t(i)%a=',t1(i)%a,' expected t(i)%a=',i,': ',merge('ERROR!','OK    ',t1(i)%a/=i)
          endif
        end do

end program test
```

as the results are (note the first line):

```
 i=           1  t(i)%a=           0  expected t(i)%a=           1 : ERROR!
 i=           3  t(i)%a=           3  expected t(i)%a=           3 : OK
 i=           5  t(i)%a=           5  expected t(i)%a=           5 : OK
 i=           7  t(i)%a=           7  expected t(i)%a=           7 : OK
 i=           9  t(i)%a=           9  expected t(i)%a=           9 : OK
```

My understanding is that, when running `t(1) = t(1)`, the underlying code is `call t_assign(t(1),t(1))`, which contains a `call this%destroy()`, so t(1) is deleted before copying. I'm not confortable with this:

- Is this standard conforming behavior, or is the compiler (gfortran 10.2.0) just not catching the issue?
- It's my understanding that an assignment in Fortran with the equal sign would *always* create a temporary variable, is this not the case with the overloaded subroutines?

Thanks,
Federico

Comment: `t(1)=t(1)` is not the same as `call t_assign(t(1),t(1))` but `call t_assign(t(1),(t(1)))`. With that difference, does the result follow?

Comment: well, the code just reads `t1(n) = t1(i)`, which on the first iterate, has `n==i==1`

Comment: btw: YES! if I replace `t(n)=t(i)` with `call t1(n)%assign((t1(i)))`, everything works. So looks like a compiler issue?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the linked question, but it's a _weak_ duplicate. The underlying behaviour of what _should_ happen by the standard is the same (ie., there is no aliasing), but your compiler appears to be doing it _with_ aliasing. (A bug was reported to GCC about the case of that linked question, so it's worth exploring whether that covers this case, another bug does, or whether a new bug should be opened.)

Comment: The relevant bug is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59202